# Find the volume when a curve $16x^2-(y-8)^2=32$ is rotated completely about $y$ axis between $y=0$ and $y=16$

Tags: integration, volume

Find the volume when a curve $16x^2-(y-8)^2=32$ is rotated completely about $y$ axis between $y=0$ and $y=16$
Can anyone help me with this question and a little sketching of the graph might helped.

Comment: If you are having a hard time sketching the graph, can you at least identify the object being graphed (i.e., conic section)?

Comment: I got no idea about that

Comment: Well, no offense, but maybe this problem is beyond your capability.

Answer (score 1):

Your curve looks like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16x%5E2%E2%88%92%28y%E2%88%928%29%5E2%3D32).

The volume is $V=\int_0^{16}{\pi (x(y))²dy}$.

$$\begin{align} 16x²&=32+(y-8)²\\
x²&=2+\frac{1}{16}(y-8)²\\
V&=\int_0^{16}{\pi (2+\frac{1}{16}(y-8)²)dy}\\
&=\int_0^{16}{\pi(2+\frac{1}{16}(y-8)²)dy}\\
\text{Let } u&=y-8\\
V&=\int_{-8}^{8}{\pi(2+\frac{1}{16}u²)du}
\end{align}$$
I think you can take it from here.